# Why session clears once I use fetch in javascript?

Tags: javascript, session, flask, promise

I normally use sessions in Flask (web framework) and everything works fine. However, when I send GET request via `fetch` in javascript, it seems that session is cleared (not saved).  What can be the reasons behind and are there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: What session? Assuming you are referring to a session state stored on a server, then any competent implementation will use cookies sent with the HTTPOnly flag set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used simple `xmlHttpResponse()` instead of `fetch` and everything worked as I have expected.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simply call `fetch(url)`, next time you might try `fetch(url, { credentials: 'same-origin' })`:

> `credentials`: The request credentials you want to use for the request:
>   `omit`, `same-origin`, or `include`. **To automatically send cookies for the
>   current domain, this option must be provided**. Starting with Chrome 50,
>   this property also takes a `FederatedCredential` instance or a
>   `PasswordCredential` instance.

— From [Fetch#Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters) (emphasis mine)